# Make Ionic sidemenu links add to navigation stack instead of clear

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a simple sidemenu app with the following pages:

```
  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.legal', {
    url: '/home/legal',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/legal.html',
      }
    }
  })
```

In my sidemenu, I have the following:

```
<ion-item menu-close href="#/app/home/legal">
  Legal Info
</ion-item>
```

[Here's a codepen with the same basic idea](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYpEZy)

What I want is for my "home" page to act as the parent for all (or certain) other pages that are navigated to, regardless of where the navigation action originates.  If I put a link on home.html going to #/app/home/legal it works fine, with a back button on the legal info page.

However, if I put the same link in my sidemenu, it seems to replace "home" with "legal" on the navigation stack, and there is no back button and the hardware back button causes the app to close.

Is there something really simple I'm missing, or do I need some sort of workaround to do that?

Comment: can you provide codepen or plunker for same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check i replace menu-close to menu-toggle

```
<ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <ul class="list">
                <a href="#/app/home" class="item" menu-close>href="#/app/home"</a>
                <a href="#/app/home/legal" class="item" menu-toggle>href="#/app/home/legal"</a>
           </ul>
         </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

Comment: That did it, thanks.  Now that I check the menu-close documentation I see that it does mention that it clears the navigation stack.